# Website Layout Statistics

Tags: web-statistics

I have a client who has suggested laying out a long list of categories in a custom order. The order is to be decided by them based on product items they sell the most etc.

I tend to disagree and feel that people browsing the internet prefer to search lists of categories that are in alphabetical order or sorted by something they can take reference of such as a date.

I would like to know others thoughts on this and it would be appreciated if anyone could point me in the direction of any open source surveys that have been taken in this area.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

What a silly stance to take regarding a simple customer request. Allow for both orderings, and other ones too. There is no survey that will demonstrate that the client is wrong as they are - by definition - correct.

Code that allows for different orderings has greater utility anyway, and real user data will be able to show them which - if either - should be the default.

Comment: I did not take the stance as I am well aware the customer is always right. It was just my opinion. I thought if there was some survey or stats on the matter I could offer it to them for reading, they are a reasonable client and prepared to be offered valuable advice that could help there business. The site is built on Wordpress so there are no problems changing the order of the data. I could also implement client side sorting and save it in a cookie so every user could choose their preference but seems like overkill.

Comment: Overkill? Without user metrics you actually have no idea. That you are trying to convince some anonymous schmoe on the internet (me) that your approach is correct is kinda further evidence that your thinking incorrectly about the whole matter.